# Return data in UploadTask onSuccessListener

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload multiple files to Firebase and would like to link it to another child when all the upload tasks are completed. To achieve this, I was trying to use coroutines in kotlin. Below is the code (Please correct me if I am wrong as I'm really bad in coroutines):

```
fun create(placemark: PlacemarkModel,callback: () -> Unit=fun(){})=runBlocking {
    val key = db.child("users").child(userId).child("placemarks").push().key
    placemark.id = key!!
    placemarks.add(placemark)
db.child("users").child(userId).child("placemarks").child(key).setValue(placemark)            
    uploadImage(placemark.dp,"dp",placemark)
    if (placemark.images.size>0){
      placemark.images.forEach{
      uploadImage(it,"images",placemark,placemark.images.indexOf(it))
    }
}
```

And here is my `uploadImage` function which I intended to wait until it finishes running and pass back the URI to the main function

```
suspend fun uploadImage(image:String,
             type:String,
             placemark: PlacemarkModel,
             index:Int=0,
             callback:()->Unit=fun(){}):URI{
    st = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference
    info("Coroutines 2")
    val imageRef = st?.child(userId + '/' + File(image).name)
    val data=readAndCompress(image)
    data?.let {
    var uploadTask=imageRef?.putBytes(data)
    uploadTask?.addOnFailureListener {
      println(it.message)
    }?.addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
      //I want to return the URI here however return is not allowed
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I am not familiar with Kotlin, but in Java when I need to run something based on the number of images uploaded to Firebase, I put a checker inside the for loop for image index. for ex. for( int i=0; i<arrayList.size(); i++){  if(i == arrayList.size()-1) { //do the function needed to execute when final loop is done  } }

Comment: I dont think this will work.  I need to link the uploaded file to my child and this method will not wait until the file completely uploaded. Hence my child will have no reference to the image

Comment: I was hoping using addOnCompleteListener to upload would be obvious. I was only answering for te array index part of the problem. You can have addOnCompleteListener /  addOnSuccessListener to upload taks in Firebase, and that way you can implement your logic on completion / success of your upload

Comment: maybe using forEach is making this less obvious. Either way, let me know if face any hurdles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I can add all the tasks in to list of Task and call

> Tasks.whenAllSuccess(tasks).addCompleteListener{ //callback here }